# Is there any way to check ensighten tags in Charles web debugger in commit state

Tags: charles-proxy

Is there any way to check ensighten tags in Charles web debugger in commit state.
or any other tools or extension where I can check the tag

Answer (score 1):

By default tags are served off nexus.ensighten.com, if you want to use Charles or Fiddler you can use a rewrite or map-remote rule to point nexus.ensighten.com to nexus-test.ensighten.com.

Alternatively there are Firefox and Chrome extensions where you can simply toggle between the production and testing version of the code without the need for a proxy.